# Kate - select whole word under cursor via shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kate

I use **Kate** (version 3.14.2). In this text editor it is possible to select the whole word by double click on it. I would like to achieve the same effect but via keyboard shortcut. I've tried to look at "Configure Shortcuts" dialog, but didn't found such shortcut.

I'm aware of [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34740594/how-can-i-select-a-word-under-a-cursor-position-in-kate-via-shortcut). But I'm not satisfied with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> because it jumps to the next occurrence after second press. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⟵</kbd> or <kbd>⟶</kbd> also is not a solution (I would like to select the whole word under cursor, not segment).

Should I tune Kate's configuration files by hand, or use specific plugin (may be I've just missed something...)?